# get_result mysqli method error in local MAMP stack?

Tags: php, mysqli, mamp

Im running MAMP with PHP 5.6.2 but im getting some mysqli error, telling me that get_result method is undefined. All other mysqli methods seem to work fine though?

```
$stmt = $database->stmt_init();

if (!$stmt = $database->prepare("SELECT posts.id, title, text FROM posts JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id WHERE username = ?")) {
    $error = $stmt->error;
    $errorcode = $stmt->errno;

    throw new Exception('Get user wallpost fail error' . $error);
}else{
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $username);

    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        $array[] = $row;
    }
}
```

What could cause this error? It must be some configuration problem??

Comment: From the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) for `get_result()`: _Available only with mysqlnd_. The MySQL native drivers are generally __not__ installed. You'd need to install them for your particular set-up. Hosting companies frequently don't install them either, so you're probably better not relying on them.

Comment: hmm I have to look into that - but it would surprise me if you have to install mysql native driver manually..

Comment: The generic drivers are available as part of the MAMP stack. It's the native drivers that are omitted. You can do what you need with MySQl in other ways, but the specific function you're having trouble with is only available if `mysqlnd` is installed which, as I said, it frequently isn't.

Comment: well i need to run the code with the get_result because its a part of a larger system. i will have to try to install mysqlnd then.